# Hide server signature or token from response of application hosted on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a web app deployed on AWS ECS. The application is built on python django framework. I can see in response the server version is being displayed. What is the workaround for hiding that info. The application is deployed as a docker image.

Comment: Why don't you disable the logging in the application level?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these Steps
1. First, you need to create customize middlewares in your app folder like **your_app_name/middleware.py** 
middleware.py

```
class RemoveHeaders(object):
   def __init__(self, get_response):
     self.get_response = get_response
   def __call__(self, request):
     response = self.get_response(request)
     response['Server'] = "My value"
     return response
```

2.Then go to your project setting **yourproject/settings.py** and you will see Middleware block in setting.py file add this '**your_app_name.middleware_file_name.class_name**' inside your middleware block

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

               'your_app_name.middleware.RemoveHeaders',

             ]
```

For more information you can open this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware